# ANT doesn't get exit code return by a python script

Tags: python, ant, build, scripting

I'm currently using ant for building my java project on a Windows XP machine. I have different tasks defined in the build.xml and one of this is the exec of a Python script for analyzing the application output.
I would like to make ANT failing when a particolar tag is discovered by script. I'm trying using:

```
sys.exit(1)
```

or

```
os.system("EXIT 1")
```

the second one in particular execute the console command EXIT which successfully make the building process failing if executed inside a bath file.Unfortunately ant is not able to reveal the exit code from inside the launched script and goes on normally till the end showing a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message.

the script is called in this way:

```
<exec dir="${path}/scripts" executable="python">
        <arg line='log_analysis.py results.log" ' />
    </exec>
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
<exec dir="${path}/scripts" executable="python" failonerror="true">
    <arg line="log_analysis.py results.log" />
</exec>
```

Ant does not stop the build process if the command exits with a return code signaling failure by default; you have to set `failonerror="true"` to do that.