# Automating launch of a python selenium script

Tags: python, selenium, cron

I am trying to crontab a python/selenium script but obviously this won't work since Firefox requires a display, I went down the PyVirtualDisplay / xvfb route but this won't give me visual feedback, I don't want to run the script headless,I just want it to launch automatically like if I was entering the command line by hand in the terminal, just automatic . Would you know of a way to do it without going through the crontab/headless route ?

thank you ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run your test in background but same time you can see browser when you want, try this:

1. Install CI and run it service by your user (try [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), google will help you)
2. Write Ant Script, it will help to automate the run. ([URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004057/ant-doesnt-get-exit-code-return-by-a-python-script))

I'm using CI and Ant to run my test by schedule and when i want buy one click. Good luck maybe this will help you.